# Clang - Zero section name on Windows

Tags: c, clang

Clang 16 on Windows does not create a section name, how to fix it?

cff explorer:
[prev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tiwD.png)

mycode:

```
#pragma clang section bss=".pad"
u8 pages[pages_cnt * PAGE_4KB];
#pragma clang section bss=""
```

Different stackoverflow solutions

```
#pragma bss_seg
```

Comment: [Quote:](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#specifying-section-names-for-global-objects-pragma-clang-section) *This feature is only defined to work sensibly for ELF targets*